# Get last element in a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, collections, sorteddictionary

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018168/how-can-i-return-the-last-element-in-a-dictionary-in-c).

How can I get the last element in a SortedDictionary in .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var lastItem = sortedDict.Values.Last();
```

You can also get the last key:

```
var lastkey = sortedDict.Keys.Last();
```

You can even get the last key-value pair:

```
var lastKeyValuePair = sortedDict.Last();
```

This will give you a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` with `Key` and `Value` properties.

Note that this will throw an exception if the dictionary is empty; if you don't want that, call `LastOrDefault`.

Comment: These methods likely trigger enumeration. I wonder if there is any way to get the last element (or element from any position index) without enumeration? Since the SortedDictionary is sorted into a tree, it could be in theory possible?

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: In theory, yes.   In practice, I don't think so.

Comment: For someone from a C++ background, this is hard to accept. Enumerating through the entire sorted dictionary just to get the last element is hopelessly inefficient. Are there more capable C# Collection libraries around?

Comment: This is very old, indeed, however, someone may answer my question. Is it not possible to try *sortedDic.Keys[sortedDic.Keys.Count - 1]* instead, in order to get the last key?

Comment: @ThunderGr: No; it doesn't have an indexer.

Comment: You can create a class, inherit SortedDictionary, and override the Add-method. There you can call the original Add method, and save the last added element. Then just add a Last-property, which returns this last added element.

Comment: @Lander: That will completely break as soon as you remove an element.

Comment: @SLaks: That's true. In my case elements are never removed, but we don't know if that's also the case in the situation of the OP.

Answer (score 27):

`Last` extension method will give you the result, but it will have to enumerate the entire collection to get you there. It's such a shame `SortedDictionary<K, V>` doesn't expose `Min` and `Max` members especially considering internally it is backed by a `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` which has `Min` and `Max` properties.

If O(n) is not desirable, you have a few options:

1. Switch to a `SortedList<K, V>`. Again for some reason BCL doesn't pack this by default. You can use indexers to get max (or min) value in O(1) time. Extending with extension methods will be nice.

   ```
   //Ensure you dont call Min Linq extension method.
   public KeyValuePair<K, V> Min<K, V>(this SortedList<K, V> dict)
   {
       return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(dict.Keys[0], dict.Values[0]); //is O(1)
   }

   //Ensure you dont call Max Linq extension method.
   public KeyValuePair<K, V> Max<K, V>(this SortedList<K, V> dict)
   {
       var index = dict.Count - 1; //O(1) again
       return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(dict.Keys[index], dict.Values[index]);
   }
   ```

   `SortedList<K, V>` comes with other penalties. So you might want to see: [What's the difference between SortedList and SortedDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary)
2. Write your own `SortedDictionary<K, V>` class. This is very trivial. Have a `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` as the internal container and base the comparison on the `Key` part. Something like:

   ```
   public class SortedDictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>
   {
       SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>> set; //initialize with appropriate comparer

       public KeyValuePair<K, V> Min { get { return set.Min; } } //O(log n)
       public KeyValuePair<K, V> Max { get { return set.Max; } } //O(log n)
   }
   ```

   This is O(log n). Not documented, but I checked the code.
3. Use fiddly reflection to access the backing set which is private member of `SortedDictionary<K, V>` class and invoke `Min` and `Max` properties. One can rely on expressions to compile a delegate and cache it for performance. It's a very poor choice to do so. Can't believe I suggested this.
4. Rely on other implementations, for eg. For [`TreeDictionary<K, V>` from C5](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.TreeDictionary%602.htm). They have [`FindMin`](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.SortedDictionaryBase%602.htm#M:C5.SortedDictionaryBase%602.FindMin) and [`FindMax`](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.SortedDictionaryBase%602.htm#M:C5.SortedDictionaryBase%602.FindMax) [both of which are O(log n)](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/PreRelease0.5/userguide.htm)

Comment: Might want to re-order these options so that the better options are at the top, rather than having them in, what I presume, is the order that you thought of them.

Comment: How would you implement the indexer/`TryGetValue` for your second option?

Comment: @CodesInChaos you're right, that makes it useless. It's sad sets in .NET don't expose a way to get the actual reference. I should edit the answer.

Comment: It is still an open issue in GitHub: [SortedDictionary.First performance](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18668). It seems that for some reason they don't like adding new functionality to existing collection types.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SortedDictionary.Values.Last();`

or if you want the key and the value

```
SortedDictionary.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

SortedList list...

```
list[ Keys[Keys.Count - 1] ];  // returns the last entry in list
```

Answer (score 0):

As folks have already pointed **Last** extension will enumerate the entire collection, its impact on perf can be deadly.
Just to remove 10000 last elements from SortedDict, it took a lot more time than similar operation on SortedSet.

1. SortedSet Removal Elapsed ms : 8
2. SortedDict Removal Elapsed ms : 3697

   // In below code,ss is SortedSet and sd is SortedDictionary and both contain same 10000 elements.

   ```
    sw.Start();
    while (ss.Count != 0)
    {
        ss.Remove(ss.Max);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("SortedSet Removal Elapsed ms : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();
    while (sd.Count != 0)
    {
        sd.Remove(sd.Keys.Last());
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Dict Removal Elapsed ms : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
   ```