# Unity : How to get last value element, in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, c#-3.0

How to get last element in Dictionary.

i search that. but i could not find answer.. just use .NET framework 3.5  this way dic.Values.Last(); 
but it doesn't in unity 3.5.5..

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: ok. thanks. im rookie of stackoverflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the last element in a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018168/get-the-last-element-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Please see similar [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018168/how-can-i-return-the-last-element-in-a-dictionary-in-c). Namely the "last" item in values isn't necessarily the "last" item you added to the dictionary.  If order is important, use a list.